# Roots of polynomials those coefficients are analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

We say a power series in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$ is analytic, if it has a positive radius of convergence.

Let $P(T) = \sum_{i=0}^n u_iT^i$ be a polynomial those coefficients $u_i \in \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ are analytic power series and let $f \in \mathbb{C}[[z]]$ be a root of $P$.

**Question:** Is $f$ analytic ?

Background: If the answer is "yes", any non-analytic power series would be transcendental over the ring of analytic power series. This would produce a counter-example to the second question in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266198/how-to-pass-from-algebraic-power-series-to-the-analytic-ones/266216#266216.

Comment: It is enough to show the root is holomorphic somewhere.

Comment: If you replace $T(z)$ by $T(z_0)+T'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(z-z_0)$ the same for $u_i(z) = u_i(z_0)+u_i'(z_0)(z-z_0)+o(z-z_0)$ and solve the obtained algebraic equation in $T(z_0),T'(z_0)$, is it enough for showing $T(z)$ is complex differentiable, and then holomorphic ?

Comment: "Over what field": Over the field of functions that are meromorphic in an open disc around the origin.

Comment: Yes, it is enough to show that $f$ is holomorphic around the origin.

Comment: It won't have to be : $z^{1/2}$ the solution of $T^2-z = 0$ has a branch point at $z=0$. But it is "locally holomorphic" (whatever it means)

Comment: If you fix $z$ then $P_u(X) = \sum_{i=0}^d u_i(z) X^i = 0$ is an algebraic equation in $X$. Fix $i$ and assume $u_i(z) \ne 0$, then the roots of $P_u$ move holomorphically with respect to $u_i(z)$, and this is all we need I'd say

Comment: Concerning $T^2-z=0$: Note that this polynomial has no root in $\mathbb{C}[[z]]$. So the example doesn't apply to the question.

Comment: $T_U(X) = X^n+\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} U_{i+1} X^m = \prod_{k=1}^n (X-\rho_k(U))$ where each $\rho_k$ is (locally) analytic $\mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}$. Composing with the holomorphic curve $u : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}^n$ makes $\rho_k \circ u(z)$ holomorphic (except at the branch points, where one of the $u_i(z)$ vanish). This way it is clear that $u_i$ polynomial/rational or holomorphic/meromorphic doesn't change anything in the argument.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes.

**Proof:** Let $F$ be the field of Puiseux series over $\mathbb{C}$. Each $g  \in F$ can be written as $g(z)=h(z^{1/r})$ where $h(z)=z^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ and $k$ an integer. $g$ is called an analytic Puiseux series, if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ is analytic. Denote the set of analytic Puiseux series by $F_a$. We will use the Newton-Puiseux Theorem from ["Nowak: Some elementary proofs of Puiseux's Theorem"](http://www.emis.de/journals/UIAM/actamath/PDF/38-279-282.pdf) (in the paper "analytic" is called "convergent"):

> $F$ and $F_a$ are algebraically closed fields.

$P$ (from the question) is a polynomial over $F_a\subseteq F$, so its roots $f_1,...,f_n$ are in $F_a$. Since $f \in \mathbb{C}[[z]] \subseteq F$ is also a root of $P$, there is an $i$ such that $f=f_i$. Hence $f \in F_a$ is an analytic Puiseux series and because $f$ is a power series, it's an analytic power series. Q.E.D.